# Change color of Bootstrap navbar links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Basically problem with this code is that I can't change the color of the nav bar links, from black to white.

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

body {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.collapse .navbar-collapse {
  color: #FFFF;
}

nav .navbar {
  color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:#670303" style="color:#FFFF">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="logo.svg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" style="color:#FFFF">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">Disabled</a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </nav>

















  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

The problem with navbar is that I can't change default color which is black to be white. No idea why? I added color value to certain classes hoping it would change but nothing.

[image]

Comment: You might want to use `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link { color: #fff; }` Similarly you need to use it for active and disabled using the multiple class selected like `navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active`

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to overwrite the `already-implemented` class by `bootstrap`.

`.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link` indicates the `nav links` on your hamburger menu. So it is needed to overwrite the color there.

And it has many color changes when `hover`, `focus` or etc so simply, to apply the color changes, it's good to use `!important` on `color` css attribute.

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

body {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.collapse .navbar-collapse {
  color: #FFFF;
}

nav .navbar {
  color: #FFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:#670303" style="color:#FFFF">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="logo.svg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" style="color:#FFFF">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">Disabled</a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </nav>

















  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You wanna overwrite other things from Bootstrap, to overwrite them just add a `!important` after your value

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link{
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:#670303" style="color:#FFFF">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="logo.svg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" style="color:#FFFF">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">Disabled</a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </nav>

















  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>

</html>
```